What to do with a stock whose isin is active but company is delisted?
I am from India and i have a share in my demat account that is delisted but the isin is active. Because of this share I am not able to close the demat account and i am losing money in maintaining that demat account. How to get out of this situation?

Why don't you ask the bank?

They are telling to transfer the shares to some other account. I don't have any. And they are telling that's the only way

Have you told them that? And ask for a solution? There can't just be one way to do something and no alternative especially if the alternative is not present per your claim (aka another account).

I told them that and they were like there are no other way and that's why I am here.

Ok, but if the entity who is supposed to do it presumably has no way, how can we help here?

I was wondering whether anyone else is facing the same issue and their bank has suggested a different way

Best of luck to you, I hope you get it resolved.
